# Combining textures with common alpha

Tags: c++, directx

I have two textures with an alpha channel that I need to 'combine' in the following way: `result_alpha = 1 - (1 - alpha_1) * (1 - alpha_2)`. I can do this with some render state manipulation:

```
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA); // note the inversion
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);

device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE | D3DTA_COMPLEMENT);

device->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
device->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE | D3DTA_COMPLEMENT);
```

However, I also need to modulate the result with a constant alpha value, and I'm not sure how to do that. If I simply set that alpha in diffuse color, the result will be in `(1-alpha, 1)` range instead of `(0, alpha)`.

Comment: Have you tried to add another stage with a `D3DTSS_CONSTANT`, where you can modulate with a fix value?

Comment: Like, have the 3 actual textures do D3DTOP_ADDSMOOTH and the 4th multiply it by a constant? Sounds like a good idea, I'll try it.